# kdb+/q tickerplant : what is `timesym?

Tags: kdb

I am following [test tickerplant and feedhandler setup](https://code.kx.com/q/wp/capi/#test-tickerplant-and-feedhandler-setup) instructions. However, when I try to run `q tick.q someTable tick_log -p 5555` I get the following error: `'timesym`. There is nothing about it in the above mentioned *"C API for kdb+"* white paper. What I did:

- downloaded https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick.q
- `mkdir tick`
- put u.q from https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick/u.q into `tick/`
- put `someTable` schema into `tick/someTable.q` (contains `sym` and `time` columns)
- `mkdir tick_log`
- ran the above `q tick.q someTable tick_log -p 5555` command

Could you please help me to understand what is the meaning of the `timesym` variable and how I should supply it? Am I missing some steps?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'timesym` is an error thrown by the tickerplant if the first two columns in the table being consumed are not `time` & `sym` respectively. You can spot where the error is occuring on [line 30 of tick.q](https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick.q#L30), in the `.u.tick` function (search for `timesym`).

In order to resolve this issue, you need to ensure `time` & `sym` are the first two columns of the table (in this order). Alternatively, you could change the tickerplant code to suit your table.